# Iterate array and leave one out in each step

Tags: ruby

How do I iterate the elements of an array in Ruby and in each step I can do something with the array containing all elements, except the one that is iterated in the moment?

For instance for `[4,2,8]` I iterate the elements and then I can do something with

- `[2,8]`
- `[4,8]`
- `[4,2]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>It's not really directly possible</s> (unless you do not need the missing element). But you can program it yourself:

**Option 1 - just do it**:

```
a = [11,22,33,44,55]

a.each_with_index { |e,i|
  p e
  p a.take(i) + a[i+1..-1]
}
```

**Option 2 - integrate with Array**:

```
class Array
  def each_excluded(&block)
    self.each_with_index { |e, i|
      yield(e, self.take(i) + self[i+1..-1])
    }
  end
end

a.each_excluded { |e, rest|
  p e
  p rest
}
```

Output from either one:

```
11
[22, 33, 44, 55]
22
[11, 33, 44, 55]
33
[11, 22, 44, 55]
44
[11, 22, 33, 55]
55
[11, 22, 33, 44]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [slice method](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-slice) and create a new array with the items except for the one in which have the index for.

Comment: `Drops first n elements from ary and returns the rest of the elements in an array.` I only want to drop one element.

Comment: See edit - slice method instead (I must have misread the docs).

Answer (score 0):

```
[4, 2, 8].tap{|a| a.length.times{|i| 
  do_something_you_want_with(a[0...i]+a[i+1..-1])
}}
```

or

```
class Array
  def each_but_one &pr
    length.times{|i| pr.call(self[0...i]+self[i+1..-1])}
  end
end

[4, 2, 8].each_but_one{|a| do_something_you_want_with(a)}
```

Answer (score 0):

It really looks like you want [`Array#combination`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-combination):

```
[4,2,8].combination(2).each do |ary|
  p ary
end
```

Which outputs:

```
[4, 2]
[4, 8]
[2, 8]
```

Each sub-array created is yielded to the block, in this case to `ary`, so you can do what you want with the values.